# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property WebView has not been initialized

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-studio, kotlin

I created an android app and loading an html file on android webView. Which is loaded successfully and working fine.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var myAndroidWebView: WebView;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setWebviewDetails();
    }

    private fun setWebviewDetails(){
        //if(!::myAndroidWebView.isInitialized){
        myAndroidWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //}
        myAndroidWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true;
        myAndroidWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/App/index.html");
        myAndroidWebView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "AndroidApp");
    }
    
    public fun testMessage(param: String){
        println("Interface call-2")
        myAndroidWebView.post(Runnable {
            val str = "xxxXXXXXXXXXXXXXx $param"
            myAndroidWebView.loadUrl("javascript:Application.UserInterface.sample('$str')")
        })
        println("Interface call-3")
    }
}
```

Now I want to send message to Android app to JS and vice versa.
I have a button in HTML and triggeting the function

```
public fun showToast(toast: String) {}
```

From HTML view by using, `AndroidApp.showToast("hello");`
Which is working fine and I am getting call from JS to Android interface function `showToast()`

Now on request from the JS I want to get some values from Android and send back to JS as well.
I have an interface, on trigger button from HTML I am getting call on the below interface function.
And trying to call a method in the `MainActivity`,  `public fun testMessage(param: String){}` is triggered succssfully.

**Issue:
I am trying to send data to JS by using,**

```
myAndroidWebView.loadUrl("javascript:Application.UserInterface.sample('$str')")
```

Here I am getting error.

```
W/System.err: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property myAndroidWebView has not been initialized
```

How do I resolve it.
Thanks.

```
    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context  */

class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context) {
    var mainActivity:MainActivity = MainActivity();

    /** Show a toast from the web page  */

    @JavascriptInterface
    public fun showToast(toast: String) {
        println("Interface call-1")
        mainActivity.testMessage(mContext,toast);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lateinit property not initialized` exception is thrown because you are trying to create an instance of MainActivity in WebInterface. `var mainActivity:MainActivity = MainActivity();`

It is Android system's job to create and load your activities. You should never *try to initiate an activity*.

Here, a rough improvement of your code. Try to adapt it to your needs.

```kotlin
interface JsCommunicator {
  fun testMessage(param: String)
}

class WebAppInterface(private val communicator: JsCommunicator) {
  @JavascriptInterface
  fun showToast(toast: String) {
    communicator.testMessage(toast)
  }
}

class YourMainActivity : JsCommunicator {
  // ...

  private lateinit var myAndroidWebView: WebView
  override fun testMessage(param: String) {
    println("Interface call-2")
    myAndroidWebView.post(Runnable {
      val str = "xxxXXXXXXXXXXXXXx $param"
      myAndroidWebView.loadUrl("javascript:Application.UserInterface.sample('$str')")
    })
    println("Interface call-3")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You are accessing web-view without initialising it.
call setWebviewDetails() first then testMessage() 
or you can make webview nullable like this
private var myAndroidWebView: WebView? = null;

also you need to call startActivity() to create Activity not by 
creating objects as this is framework class managed by Android 
System.
```